# Should I put shuffle=True or False in sklearn KFold cross validation?

Tags: scikit-learn, k-fold

I'm studying some cross_validation scores on my dataset using `cross_val_score` and `KFold`
In particular my code looks like this:

```
cross_val_score(estimator=model, X=X, y=y, scoring='r2', cv=KFold(shuffle=True))
```

My question is if it's a common behaviour to put `shuffle=True` inside the `KFold`: if I do it the returns on the r2 score are:

```
[0.5934, 0.60432, 0.45689, 0.6875, 0.5678]
```

If I put `shuffle=False` it returns

```
[0.3987, 0,4576, 0.3234, 0.4567. 0.3233]
```

I would not want that same points that are used for training on an iteration would be then reconsidered for the next, ending up with an optimistic score for the cross validation.. How should I explain that I get better scores using `shuffle=True` ?

Answer (score 4):

The general procedure for cross-validation requires the dataset to be shuffled randomly.

If data is unordered in nature (i.e. non - Time series)  then `shuffle=True` is right choice.

Note :

`train_test_split` in `sklearn` has `shuffle=True` by default.

Further Read :

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#a-note-on-shuffling

https://www.kaggle.com/general/236904